# What are all the available ACL attributes in Mac OS 10.13 High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, permission, acl

In Mac OS, file and folder access permissions are managed in a layered way with basic unix (POSIX) style: `owner/group/everyone` and `read/write/execute` modes along with, recently added *Access Control Lists* (ACL) for additional access control.

Both the POSIX and ACL controls can be managed from the command line with the traditional unix command `chmod`. For example:

```
Mac:~> sudo chmod -R +a "staff allow list,addfile,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown,file_inherit,directoryinherit" path/to/folder*
```

What is the comprehensive list of all ACL attributes which are settable in Mac OS 10.13 (High Sierra)? What does each mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A comprehensive list of ACL attributes is available by consulting the man pages:

```
man chmod
```

If you prefer a GUI app to show man pages download and install e.g. [ManOpen](http://www.clindberg.org/projects/manopen.html) (free) or [Dash for macOS](https://kapeli.com/dash) (a few $$).

I won't list the whole documentation of chmod:

> ```
> ...
>
> ACL MANIPULATION OPTIONS
>
>
>  ACLs are manipulated using extensions to the symbolic mode grammar.  Each
>  file has one ACL, containing an ordered list of entries.  Each entry
>  refers to a user or group, and grants or denies a set of permissions.  In
>  cases where a user and a group exist with the same name, the user/group
>  name can be prefixed with "user:" or "group:" in order to specify the
>  type of name.
>
>  If the user or group name contains spaces you can use ':' as the delim-
>  iter between name and permission.
>
>  The following permissions are applicable to all filesystem objects:
>        delete  Delete the item.  Deletion may be granted by either this
>                permission on an object or the delete_child right on the
>                containing directory.
>        readattr
>                Read an objects basic attributes.  This is implicitly
>                granted if the object can be looked up and not explicitly
>                denied.
>        writeattr
>                Write an object's basic attributes.
>        ...
> ```

Comment: So embarrassing! RTFM! uggh.  Mac OS _is_ Unix. They have man pages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. +1. The man page shows all the ACL permissions.

Comment: The full list (on Mojave): delete
readattr
writeattr
readextattr
writeextattr
readsecurity
writesecurity
chown
list
search
add_file
add_subdirectory
delete_child
read
write
append
execute
file_inherit
directory_inherit
limit_inherit
only_inherit